# Using Gmap.net markers with timers

Tags: c#

I am developing a function that if user  chooses a car from a car list then the car will be represented by a marker on Google Map.
how to make marker  flashes   in a regular way using timer?
remark i am using Gmap.net Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this way to control your timer before you call the event of the timer

```
if (timerName != null)
{
  timerName.Stop();
  timerName.Dispose();
  timerName = new Timer();
}
timerName.Tick += new EventHandler(timerName_Tick);
```